# Consume a web service in android application

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am getting into Android development and I have a question about calling a web service.

I have a web service written in PHP (lets say service.php).

To my knowledge in service.php I have to echo/print whatever I want the service call to return, is that correct?

Also, as this is a PHP service, is there a way to call a certain function (rather than using the querystring to decide).

Like in WCF I would call service.svc/GetUser/foobar (meaning get member foobar.

Comment: any code snip you hv wriiten in android kindly post it.

Comment: @siddiboy An example is welcome. What I mean is, is there a way for my service to return data without having to print it to the screen?